# Arduino: How to beginTransmission inside onReceive

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I have 3 Arduinos that are connected via I2C.
My goal is to send a data from slave1 to master and then after that send that data from master to slave 2.

My problem is that, whenever I use beginTransmission, it does not send the data from master to slave 2.

Here is the example of my code:

```
//Wire Master 
#include<Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);
void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("Ref Door Status");
  Wire.begin(1);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.onReceive(receivedEvent);
}



void loop() {
  /*Wire.requestFrom(9,1);
  while(Wire.available()){
    c = Wire.read();
    if(c=='O'){
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("OPEN");
    }
    
    else if (c == 'C'){
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("CLOSE");
    }
  }*/
}

void receivedEvent(int howMany){
  while(Wire.available()){
    char c = Wire.read();
    if(c=='O'){
      //openRef();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("OPENED");
      Wire.beginTransmission(8);
      Wire.write('O');
      Wire.endTransmission();
      
    }
    
    else if (c == 'C'){
      //closeRef();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print("CLOSED");
    }
  }
}
```

I really would appreciate your help.

Comment: For me, there is a conflict between your loop and your event. Can you try to remove code from loop and only work in the event?

Comment: Yes, I tried to remove the code in the loop but still works that way.

Comment: Have you make sure that you are going into the received event? Try to print something on the console